# email validation error even after valid email id input

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using following script to validate email. but even after entering valid email, it is showing error message as "enter valid email id"...

code is as follows...

```
   if(joms.jQuery('#jsemail').val() !=  joms.jQuery('#email').val())
{
    regex=/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,4}$/;
    isValid = regex.test(joms.jQuery('#jsemail').val());

    var fieldname = joms.jQuery('#jsemail').attr('name');;
    if(isValid == false){
        cvalidate.setMessage(fieldname, '', 'COM_COMMUNITY_INVALID_EMAIL');
        joms.jQuery('#jsemail').addClass('invalid');
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend JQuery validate plugin. http://jqueryvalidation.org/. It not only has plenty features for e-mail validation, but form validation in general.

Comment: You should tag this with "jquery".  Having it tagged with just "validation" is really going to limit the number of folks who notice it.

Comment: Please use  jquery validation plugin , i implemented it http://linux.aress.net/ESCtNewWeb/

Comment: please evaluate the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
function emailValidation()
{
value=joms.jQuery('#jsemail').val();
if(value == '') 
    return true;

var temp1;
temp1 = true;
var ind = value.indexOf('@');
var str2=value.substr(ind+1);
var str3=str2.substr(0,str2.indexOf('.'));
if(str3.lastIndexOf('-')==(str3.length-1)||(str3.indexOf('-')!=str3.lastIndexOf('-')))
    return false;
var str1=value.substr(0,ind);
if((str1.lastIndexOf('_')==(str1.length-1))||(str1.lastIndexOf('.')==(str1.length-1))||(str1.lastIndexOf('-')==(str1.length-1)))
    return false;
str = /(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\._-]{0,1})+([a-zA-Z0-9]+[_]{0,1})*@([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-]{0,1})+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/;
temp1 = str.test(value);
return temp1;
}
```